# Visual Studio 2013 fill DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, datagrid

I'm trying to read data from a SQLite database. Then I'd like to fill it into my DataGrid, but the following code doesn't work (**dataUrl is the DataGrid-Object**):

```
    string sql = "SELECT rowid, url FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%@search%'";
    SQLiteConnection myConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\URL Store\URL Store\bin\Release\urlStore.sqlite;Version=3;Password=*censored*;");
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConnection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", txtSearch.Text);
    myConnection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet set = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        //            
        //ESPECIALLY THIS PART IS IMPORTANT TO ME
        //
        adapter.Fill(set);
        DataTable table = set.Tables[0];
        dataUrl.DataContext = table;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading data!");
    }
```

It does't even throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `ItemsSource` instead of `DataContext` and for that you need to get `DataView` as it only accepts `IEnumerable`:

```
dataUrl.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

or

```
dataUrl.ItemsSource = new DataView(table);
```

also remove `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.

also, because you use parameters and `AddWithValue(..)`, your query should look like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT rowid, url FROM urls WHERE url LIKE @search";
```

and you add parameter like this instead:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + txtSearch.Text + "%");
```

which is the whole point of using parameters

Comment: This worked better. The DataGrid is now showing the headlines of the table, but no entries.

Comment: Have you checked your SQL in a commandline? Or at least debug the result of the query.

Comment: @SoBiT, remove `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` and see if it works then

Comment: @dkozl It should not have any impact on the result :)

Comment: Fantastic, changing the way to set the parameters was the solution! Thanks!